# Dimming 2 recessed light strings with 1 light in common

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I'd like to implement something like this :

[image]

I.e. Having 2 groups of lights with one light able to be controlled from both dimmers (1 & 2 on the picture).
Is it possible?

I'm not sure, from what I've read, that multi-location dimmers could do that, because usually they're for one load.
One way to do it would be to have at Light #4 a "voltage selector device" that would take for example the highest AC line voltage between the two, and output it to light #4.
There would be to have a way, when Group 1 and 2 are turned on, to "prioritize" either dimmer 1 or dimmer 2 to control light #4.

The reason I want this is because the lobby and the kitchen have this light in common, and without that light, the spot that is lighted up by light 4 is quite dark. Being able to control it from both location would be very handy, and make much better lighting.

Thanks!

Comment: A [0-10V lighting control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0-10_V_lighting_control) system with the input to Light 4 provided through diodes from both dimmers might work if the lights had 0-10V dimming inputs. Not getting a warm and fuzzy feeling from this one. (That's assuming that the negative sides of the 0-10V signals from both dimmers can be connected together. Perhaps a bad assumption.)

Comment: Are smart switches/dimmers an option here?

Comment: All options are on the table no matter the cost. Of course the cheapest the better, but I understand this isn't too common, so I assume it will be more expensive than a standard setup.

Comment: Another (lonely) thought: If you go the 0-10V route you'll want diodes with a low forward voltage (aka voltage drop) to minimize the brightness difference between Light 4 and the rest of the lights. A drop of 0.6V would make Light 4 always run 6% _of the maximum brightness_ lower than the other lights. At full power that might not be very noticeable, but if you plan to run the lights at low levels it will be much more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Only 2 ways I know. Neither pretty.

### Put two bulbs in the common light

This is a common tactic in multi-unit flats, a 2 or 3 bulb fixture with hot-neutral brought out for each bulb.  That allows each flat to control its bulb independently. I've lived in a place like that, and when all 3 of us have our switch on, it's downright dazzling in the entry!

This will require tricky procurement.

### Smart dimmers

Three(!) smart dimmers talking on a smart hub platform of some kind.   One of the dimmers does not need to have a human-accessible control, it can be an in-fixture module.

Then you write a snippet of code so that everytime one of the 2 dimmers is changed, the 3rd dimmer is set to the higher of the 2 settings.

Comment: The multi bulb is actually clever. Except I don't understand where I could find a recessed light (those I'm trying to control are recessed lights!) that fits 2 bulbs and that doesn't look disproportionately big compared to the other (single light) ones!